# Change <td> Background Color After Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form inside a table. I want to change the `<td>` background color after form validation for the error. I manage to do it by inserting an if condition on each `<td>` style attribute. Is there a short way.

For example maybe by using jquery. Below is my style of codes:

```
<td style="<?php echo (!empty($msgError) && empty($purchase_mode)) ? 'background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.33);' : ''; ?> "> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="purchase_mode" value="DIRECT"/>Direct
</td>
<td style="<?php echo (!empty($msgError) && empty($purchase_category)) ? 'background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.33);' : ''; ?> ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="description" value="SUPPLY"/>SUPPLY
</td>
```

I have tried to use jquery but it will change all the `<td>` background color on the table:

```
<?php if (empty($purchase_category) || empty($purchase_mode)) { ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("td").css("background-color", "red");
        });
    </script>';
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you need to append some sort of class on t because with your current code it's targeting all `<td>` elements.

Comment: your assignment operator need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of string with all the invalid fields name property and then it will take care to set the background color for those fields:

```js
function ValidateForm(invalidFields){
$("td input").each(function(){
  if($.inArray(this.name,invalidFields) >= 0){
    $(this).parent().css("background-color","rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.33)");
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="purchase_mode" value="DIRECT" />Direct
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="description" value="SUPPLY" />SUPPLY
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="button" onclick="ValidateForm(['purchase_mode'])" value="Validate Form"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Amran please check the following suggested solution

Comment: Thanks for the help @mbadeveloper. May I know what is the difference if using this.name or this.attr()?

Comment: Because we iterate the items with selector input controls inside a td you can access to the properties directly you don't need to get the attribute using attr(), using the above coe you dont need to change your code because you need to pass only an array with the fields names that are not pass the validation criteria

Comment: Ic, do I need to put the if condition before the array. Eg: '<?php if  (!empty($description))'

Comment: No, you need to to pass the array with the fields that not pass the validation to the method

Comment: I change the code to create a button that call the validation function. You need to change it will the call to your code and create an array with the name of controls that don't pass the validation criteria

Comment: Do you have a simple example for me to check? Sorry @mbadeveloper but I'm still learning on web development

Comment: I think that this example will help you http://code.runnable.com/Uaki4q9qiqlLAACJ/how-to-validate-a-form-in-php-using-jquery-for-validation

Answer (score 1):

To do it with jQuery you need to have some sort of id for the `td` you are about to change. This could be either the `id` attribute or you use `jQuery.parent`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=purchase_mode]').parent().css("background-color", "red")
});
```

This uses the the input's name as a unique identifier, gets its parent, which is the `<td>` and sets its background color.

However, you might want to consider using a plugin for this. It is much easier to use and implement and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean I have to do it for all the input name

Answer (score 0):

You can write an if condition at the top and decide a class name conditionally. Then using Jquery Code mentioned below, change the color of td using css, I m going to show you code for one td. you can do fo the rest.

```
<?php if  (!empty($purchase_mode)){
           $class_name = "green-color";
         }  else{
           $class_name = "red-color";
    } ?>

 <!-- --- Your html code below---- -->

   <td class="<?php echo $class_name;?>"> 
       <input type="checkbox" name="purchase_mode" value="DIRECT">Direct
   </td>

 <!-- Jquery --->

 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("green-color")){
                  $(this).attr("style", "background-color:green");
            }else{
                  $(this).attr("style", "background-color:red");
            }
          });
        });
 </script>'
```